# For loop until SQL command comes back with a certain value

Tags: c#, sql, loops, for-loop

I have a SQL command I want to go check the last row of my gridview and once it changes to Y in a certain column to refresh my page.  It may take anywhere from 3-7 seconds so I want to basically loop every 250ms to run my select and once selected = Y then refresh my page and take my loading screen away.

I get my row count like this and thought about doing a if/else but that won't loop:

```
// Get last row
    int count = finalGridView.Rows.Count;
    int lastRow = count - 1;
    string item = finalGridView.Rows[lastRow].Cells[1].Text;

    // Check last row to see if it completed
    OleDbCommand checkLast = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT CAST(ACRECP as char(5) ccsid 37) FROM TRDATA WHERE ITNBR = '{item}' AND TRFMT = 'IP' ORDER BY TDATE DESC", cnTrData);

    if (checkLast.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == "Y")
    {
        //Hide popup
        loading.Visible = false;

        // Rebind
        HideUC();
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        Run command again???? 
    }
```

Comment: If you do `Thread.Sleep` then you will make your GUI thread sleep and the UI will be unresponsive. You should try and hook into the events provided by the grid view and run your SQL query.

Comment: Can you do a similar for loop though to constantly run a SQL select until the value I want comes back Y instead of N?

Comment: Stop trying to do loops in SQL or looping SQL queries. This doesn't make sense. It's terrible for performance and there are better ways.

Comment: Thanks @JacobH I'll look into other options.

Comment: @ksuProgrammer I think noone will advise you to continue with a solution of looping through SQL queries. Your problem sounds like you need to add a handler to a gridview event and run your SQL query then (preferably in async way).

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius great thanks I'll look into it

Comment: I agree with them, loops is the last resolve that you must think of. As for your query, I suggest you use ITNBER IN (SELECT ITNBR FROM TRDATA) . This might solve it, and will avoid you from using the loop

Comment: Thank you @iSR5 I will try something similar to that.. basically once ACRECP becomes Y instead of N that means the last row processed and I can take my loading screen down

Comment: @ksuProgrammer which type of DBMS engine are you using ?

Comment: @iSR5 using DB2 for this particular program.  All data is stored in AS400.

Comment: Is this a windows app? why not use a timer control

Comment: Web application.  I used a timer and it works great.  Problem is, if I set that timer for 5 seconds and the transaction takes 3 there is 2 seconds wasted.  Vice versa if I set for 5 and it may actually take 7-8 seconds then what they see when the timer refreshes isn't "live" data.  Thats why I want to check it constantly so once it does change to Y then I can refresh my page to show the updated data

Comment: @ksuProgrammer does ACRECP column have a changeable value ? meaning, is it going to change every 5 seconds ? (I'm talking DB side not C#). if yes, then why you don't use triggers on value change ? and work your way out from there, this would let the DB monitor the values and not the C#.

Comment: So basically the way it works is I send a transaction in and the ACRECP value is N until the system does it's checking based on a few things and if all are successful it changes to Y meaning that the transaction processed succesfully.  So once that happens I want to rebind my gridview showing the updated location quantity and remaining qty so it is essentially a live transaction system

Comment: @ksuProgrammer, I'm surprised that any company still running an AS/400 system would be developing in such an ad-hoc manner, and the whole approach very much stinks to high heaven. If it takes 3-7 seconds for the transaction to complete, then why poll every 250ms from the word go? At most, wait 3 seconds then poll every second - that could reduce the number of queries on the database 10- or 20-fold, and the user is unlikely to miss 0.75 seconds of their time if they are already accustomed to waiting several seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Sql Server 2005** or above, you can create an event-driven communication between your application and Sql Server using the **Sql Notification** service. You only need to have the permission to create the service in the database server, so you may call it from your application.

Just in case you need more information on this, you may follow this clear and concise tutorial right here :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/working-with-sql-notification/

Hope it helps